# How to set a value for MVC2 Html.HiddenFor from ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I tried below method, but it does not work:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email, (string)ViewData["Email"])%>

<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email, new{value = (string)ViewData["Email"]})%>
```

Plz adivce.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC data is set by the controller. A view is there only to display the data passed by a controller. Also I would recommend you using strongly typed views and view models instead of ViewData.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SomeViewModel
    {
        Email = "foo@bar.com"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the view simply:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email) %>
```